# Problems connecting to database in drupal 6

Tags: database

Whew, ok I am new to Drupal, and I am dealing with a outdated drupal site. Ive been told not to upgrade yet, so for now I am dealing with Drupal 6. I am trying to stage it on our test server, but it won't seem to connect to the database. (It returns a page that says "Site off-line" and "Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in E:\development\ump_2010\includes\file.inc on line 926") Below that, it states that I could not connect to the database:

```
The mysql error was: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

I went into the settings.php file and changed $db_url to the correct one, and $db_prefix remains empty. Where is drupal getting 'localhost' and the password from as well?

Thanks,
Austin Slominski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those values are set in `$db_url`, in the sites/default/settings.php file.

```
$db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@server_ip_or_host/databasename';
```

Comment: I didn't know there was another! Thank you. There is still one more problem though, it is saying I am using the password "Yes" still, despite the fact that I state the password in $db_url.

Comment: That string `using password: YES` is boolean. It will always say YES when you use any password, or NO when you don't use a password.